# xamarin app store rejection crash on launch

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store

As many other people, after submitting an xamarin ios app, apple told me: "We were unable to review your app as it still crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.". It is not crashing anywhere. I tested it very wel on the simulator, my iphone and ipad with the latest ios version.

Got the following settings of the project in visual studio:

**Settings tab: IOS build**
SDK version: 10.3
Link Behavior: Link all
Supported Architectures: ARMv7 + ARM64
HttpClient Implementation: Managed (default)
Perform all 32 bit float operations as 64 bit float --> checked
strip native debugging symbols --> unckecked
enable incremental builds --> unckecked
use the concurrent garbage collector --> unckecked
enable device-specific builds --> unckecked

[The crash log from apple](http://kleinprodesign.nl/_Downloads_/crashlog001.txt)

What i've tried so far:

- Link behavior: Framework SDKs only
- In my current submit: Link
  behavior --> Don't link

any ideas?

**Update 1:**
I submitted the app 8 times, they were all rejected. I will soon going to try to submit an test app writen in objective C, to test if it has something to do with the virtual machine. I am compiling everything on an Vmware Mac OSX 10.12 Sierra. I also tried the sample Nativescript APP and it also got rejected so it might have something to do with that.

Comment: My best guess, as you are already suggestion, is that you are having a too aggressive linker strategy. Did you try to debug your solution with Link all or Link Framework SDKs only, and see if you got any runtime errors?

Comment: My linking debug settings always are: link all. I got no unmanaged exceptions or runtime errors

Comment: Have you tried building and running on a device in Release configuration? That's usually how I've reproduced issues of this nature in the past.

Comment: Gonne try that, I always run it in debug mode, never in release mode

Comment: It didn't work, when I trie to run it in realease configuration it says: "Debug is not enabled in the current configuration.". Apple also rejected my build that didn't link anything (Don't Link). So none of the linking options has any effect. I submitted 4 versions: Link All, Link SDKs only, Dont Link, and one with all supported architectures. Any other Ideas?

Comment: Did you succeed in testing the release configuration? That's the first step. It's normal that the debugging is disabled in release, you can use 'Start without debugging' (Ctrl+F5).